# Run thread in background in spring boot and being able to autowire

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to build a Spring Boot application that will run a long running thread in the background but the problem I am having is that I cannot autowire spring beans in the thread (at least the way I am doing it)

I have created a repo that shows the problem I am facing

https://github.com/NikosDim/spring-boot-background-thread

In the BackgroundThread class which is my thread I want to be able to autowire objects (look for the //TODO)

Thanks

Nick

Comment: Autowire your objects in BackgroundThreadManager and pass it to BackgroundThread as constructor parameter

Comment: instead of using BackgroundThread  try to use @Async annotation for background execution  https://www.baeldung.com/spring-async

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make `BackgroundThread` a [**prototype**](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-factory-scopes-prototype) bean:

```
@Bean
@Scope(ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
public BackgroundThread backgroundThreadBean(Dep1 dep1) {
    return new BackgroundThread(dep1);
}
```

Then just inject `BackgroundThread` into `BackgroundThreadManager`:

```
@Autowired
private BackgroundThread thread;
```

If you need to create multiple instances of `BackgroundThread` dynamically then [`ObjectFactory`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/ObjectFactory.html) can be used. Inject factory into `BackgroundThreadManager`:

```
@Autowired
private ObjectFactory<BackgroundThread> backgroundThreadObjectFactory;
```

and call `ObjectFactory.getObject` method to create a new instance of `BackgroundThread`.

More info on **prototype** scope can be found [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-inject-prototype-bean-into-singleton).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is there any risk on using singleton instead of prototype?

Comment: It's ok if you are not planning to add some state to `BackgroundThread` and call it from multiple threads.